# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build when I am creating a widget in main.dart file

Tags: flutter, dart

I m creating a simple quiz app from this [link.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/basic-quiz-app-in-flutter-api/?ref=lbp) Every time I run the main. dart file, it gives me setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build error as below: The code files for main. dart and Quiz. dart is shown. What am I m doing wrong? I have searched it on the internet but nothing works for my case.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pHuY.png)

```html
import 'dart:core';


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './quiz.dart';
import './result.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _questions = const [
    {
      'questionText': 'Q1. Who created Flutter?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Facebook', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'Adobe', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'Google', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'Microsoft', 'score': -2},
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'Q2. What is Flutter?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Android Development Kit', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'IOS Development Kit', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'Web Development Kit', 'score': -2},
        {
          'text':
          'SDK to build beautiful IOS, Android, Web & Desktop Native Apps',
          'score': 10
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': ' Q3. Which programing language is used by Flutter',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Ruby', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'Dart', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'C++', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'Kotlin', 'score': -2},
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'Q4. Who created Dart programing language?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Lars Bak and Kasper Lund', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'Brendan Eich', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'Bjarne Stroustrup', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'Jeremy Ashkenas', 'score': -2},
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText':
      'Q5. Is Flutter for Web and Desktop available in stable version?',
      'answers': [
        {
          'text': 'Yes',
          'score': -2,
        },
        {'text': 'No', 'score': 10},
      ],
    },
  ];

  var _questionIndex = 0;
  var _totalScore = 0;

  void _resetQuiz() {
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = 0;
      _totalScore = 0;
    });
  }

 // Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
 // myFunction();

  _answerQuestion(int score) {
    _totalScore += score;

    setState(() {
      print('i m in set state');
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
    });
    print(_questionIndex);
    if (_questionIndex < _questions.length) {
      print('We have more questions!');
    } else {
      print('No more questions!');
    }
 }
/*
 @override
  void initState() {
   // TODO: implement initState
   super.initState();
   print("initState");
   WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
     print("WidgetsBinding");
   });
 }
*/
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Geeks for Geeks'),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF00E676),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: _questionIndex < _questions.length
              ? Quiz(
            answerQuestion: _answerQuestion,
            questionIndex: _questionIndex,
            questions: _questions,
          ) //Quiz
              : Result(_totalScore, _resetQuiz),
        ), //Padding
      ), //Scaffold
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    ); //MaterialApp
  }



}
```

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './answer.dart';
import './question.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final Function answerQuestion;

  Quiz({
    required this.questions,
    required this.answerQuestion,
    required this.questionIndex,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          questions[questionIndex]['questionText'].toString(),
        ), //Question
        ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
            .map((answer) {
              print('mapping');
              print(answerQuestion(answer['score']));
          return Answer(() => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text'].toString());
        }).toList()
      ],
    ); //Column
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `setState` method when the build method is running and has not finished building.

```dart
setState(() {
      print('i m in set state');
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
    });
```

You can use `WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback` to resolve this error which Schedules a callback after the `build` method is called.

For example:

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  setState(() {
    print('i m in set state');
    _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
  });
});
```